# How to write function simulating while loop in Scala

Tags: function, scala, while-loop

How can I write function which simulates while loop? It should takes 2 arguments: condition and expression to execute.

I tried the following:

```
val whileLoop: (Boolean,Any)=>Unit = (condition:Boolean, expression:Any) => {
 expression
 if(condition) whileLoop(condition,expression)
 () }
```

But it seems it doesn't work, e.g. i have array:

```
val arr = Array[Int](-2,5,-5,9,-3,10,3,4,1,2,0,-20)
```

Also I have variable *i*:

```
var i = 0
```

I want to print all elements of arr. I can do that with the following code:

```
while(i<arr.length) { println(tab(i)); i+=1 }
```

I would like to do the same using my **whileLoop** function. But I can't write function which takes reference to variable and modify that. I could pass that using array with only one element, e.g.

```
val nr = Array(0)
```

and function:

```
val printArray: Array[Int]=>Unit = (n:Array[Int]) => {
 println(arr(n(0)))
 n(0)+=1
 ()
}
```

and then using in my **whileLoop**:

```
whileLoop(nr(0)<arr.length, printArray)
```

After using above codes I get **StackOverflowError** and nr(0) is equals zero. Also following function:

```
val printArray: Array[Int]=>Unit = (n:Array[Int]) => {
 println(arr(nr(0)))
 nr(0)+=1
 ()
}
```

gives the same result.

How can i write correct function **whileLoop** and use that to print all **arr** elements?

Thanks in advance for advices.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main problem with your implementation is that the condition and the expression are evaluated only once, when you first call `whileLoop`. In the recursive call, you just pass a value, not an expression.

You can solve this by using by-name arguments:

```
def whileLoop(cond : =>Boolean, block : =>Unit) : Unit =
  if(cond) {
    block
    whileLoop(cond, block)
  }
```

As an example:

```
scala> val a = Array(1, 2, 3)
scala> var i = 0
scala> whileLoop(i < a.length, { println(i); i += 1 })
1
2
3
```

Note that the variables `a` and `i` are correctly referenced. Internally, the Scala compiler built a *function* for both the condition and the expression (block), and these functions maintain a reference to their environment.

Also note that for more syntactic sugar awesomeness, you can define `whileLoop` as a currified function:

```
def whileLoop(cond : =>Boolean)(block : =>Unit) : Unit =
  if(cond) {
    block
    whileLoop(cond)(block)
  }
```

This allows you to call it just like an actual while loop:

```
whileLoop(i < a.length) {
  println(a(i))
  i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i came up with: 
first of all, your function needs these 4 arguments:

```
- array which is yet to be processed
- predicate that tells the function when to stop
- function that takes the array to be processed and current state and produces a new state
- and state that is being propagated through the recurion:
```

i think the code is pretty self explanatory:

```
def whileFunc[A,B](over: Array[A], predicate: Array[A] => Boolean, apply: (Array[A],B) => B, state: B):B = {
   val doIterate = predicate(over)
   if(doIterate) whileFunc(over.tail, predicate, apply, apply(over,state)) else state
}
```

this could be made a lot nicer but i tried to keep it as simple as possible. To count all the elements in array, you would call it like so:

```
scala>     whileFunc(Array(1,2,3), (a:Array[Int]) => !a.isEmpty,(a:Array[Int],s: Int) => s + a.head, 0)
res5: Int = 6
```

to print each of the elements:

```
whileFunc[Int, Unit](Array(1,2,3), (a:Array[Int]) => !a.isEmpty,(a:Array[Int],s: Unit) => print(a.head), Unit)
123
```

By the way, if you are interested in this kind of stuff, i would recommend u buying Functional programming in Scala, there are two chapters which make you implement functions like this. It's a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks also, it's interesting alternative.